# How should I add Drupal to the usersgroup with full privilegies?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I want to change the owner of my files directory on Drupal, but.. what's the Drupal user ?

I currently only have 1 user in my unix system, who is the one who moved the files. Drupal complains it cannot edit them.

How can I add Drupal to the usersgroup with full writing access ?

chown...

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need drupal to own them, just add a group that has write access.

Drupal will perform acts as your webserver which typically will be using the www user, for Ubuntu it's `www-data`.

You can use `chgrp` to add the group and `chmod g+w` to give write permission.

You can do it recursively, so you only need to do it once.

Comment: I'll add that for Ubuntu as the asker appears to be using, that would be the www-data user and group.